# В чем преимущество разных вариантов инициализации и в чем особенность инициализации {} от ()

Tags: c++

```
int a = 5;

int a(5);

int a{5};
```

Comment: @arukasa, сразу признаюсь -- кресты не люблю и поэтому знаю плохо. 

Моя догадка -- третий вариант инициализации (`a{...}`), который семантически совпадает со вторым все же визуально менее ужасен, чем второй (который удивительно напоминает  запись то ли вызова функции, то ли ее прототипа с ошибками). Видимо осознание этого факта все же посетило ряд разработчиков языка.

(поскольку вариант (2) все же придется оставить, то альтернативный вариант объяснения с упрощением синтаксического анализатора в компиляторах и т.п. отпадает... (об этом Бьерну надо было думать значительно раньше))

Comment: да собственно никакой.

Comment: а вот если вместо int был бы большой хитрый класс, то разница может быть. Уже даже для std::vector первый вариант не скомпилиться, а два других дадут совершенно разные результаты.

Comment: @user235562  В данном конкретном примере разница в стиле программирования. Первое объявление привычно и всем понятно, даже не знающим C++. Два других объявления для фундаментальных типов просто являются плохим стилем программирования, так как лишь запутывают читающего код, и у него, как и у вас, лишь возникают вопросы, почему так сделано. Кстати сказать, вы еще забыли про объявление int x = { 5 };

Comment: @VladfromMoscow насколько я знаю, многие наоборот рекомендуют использовать фигурные скобки для унифицированного стиля

Comment: @user235562 Разница между квалифицированным программистом и начинающим точно также, как между личностью и никчемностью, состоит в том, что  квалифицированный программист или личность никогда не руководствуется тем, что "многие так делают". :) Строем ходят лишь, кто не может самостоятельно ориентироваться в этом мире.:)

Comment: @user235562 Почитайте по этой ссылке ближе к концу темы часть под названием причуды инициализации  http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000047-000-10001-0-1475597138

Comment: Между тремя вышеперичисленными строками никакой разницы нет. Если вас интересует разница между синтаксисами инициализации - так и задавайте вопрос. (Тогда не забываем также `int x = { 5 }`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй и третий вариант ничем не отличаются — это [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). Первый вариант — это [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Разница описана там же (перевод мой):

> Прямая инициализация (direct initialization) более снисходительна, чем копирующая инициализация (copy initialization). При копирующей инициализации рассматриваются лишь конструкторы, не помеченные ключевым словом `explicit`, и пользовательские конверсии типов. А при прямой инициализации рассматриваются также и `explicit`-конструкторы, и *последовательности* преобразований типов.

Для примитивных встроенных типов разницы нету. А вот для классов разница появляется. Например, если ваш класс `Complex` имеет `explicit`-конструктор из `double`, то инициализировать `Complex` нулём при помощи первого синтаксиса вы не сможете, а вот при помощи второго и третьего — вполне.

Да, я тоже не понимаю, почему нормальный разработчик должен держать эти тонкости в голове[.](/questions/242499/) Это особенность языка C++, видимо.

Comment: @VladD разве код int a{5}; не ошибка?

Comment: @perfect, в C++11 и дальше -- так можно. 

Например, g++ 4.8.2 понимает такую запись для значений -std= c++11, gnu++11, c++1y и gnu++1y

Comment: чем старше язык, тем все запутанней становится

Comment: >чем старше язык тем все запутанней становится

особенно хорошо это иллюстрируют человеческие языки, в которых исключений больше, чем правил

Comment: @DreamChild да несомненно похоже на правду

Answer (score 6):

Рассмотрим разницу кратко. Допустим у нас есть некий класс, и пишем явно

```
test x = 5;
```

что бы это отработало, класс должен иметь конструктор вида

```
test(int x) {}
```

если же сделать конструктор explicit, то это уже работать не будет.

```
explicit test(int x) {}
```

строка

```
test x(5);
```

хочет точно такого же конструктора, но будет работать с обеими конструкторами. И ровно так, как ожидается.

строка

```
test{5};
```

это уже [новомодное изобретение](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (с++11). Хочет специального конструктора

```
test(std::initializer_list<int> x) {}
```

Но этот конструктор понимает и такое

```
test x{1,2,3,4};
```

что иногда бывает очень сильно удобно.

С подобной разницей можно встретиться в случае std::vector. конструкция `std::vector<int> x(5);` создаст вектор на 5 элементов с нулями (дефолтное значение для int), а `std::vector<int> x{5};` создаст вектор на один элемент со значением 5.

Почему же многие рекомендуют способ со скобками? видимо как раз по этой причине.  Им надоело, что вектор создает именно несколько элементов (что некоторые считают неочевидным, так как `int x(5)` делает именно инициализацию) и выработали для себя привычку писать в фигурных скобках. Естественно ее и пропагандируют. Это точно также как известное [условие Йоды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B) - современные компиляторы давно научились бить по пальцам за присваивание, но программисты продолжают писать по старому.

Как же писать в реальном коде? пишите так, как требует код-стайл. Но для простых типов я все же писал просто через присваивание.

Comment: а почему с `explicit` первый вариант не работает? он же запрещает приведение типов, разве оно тут есть?

Comment: конечно есть. приводиться int к test.

Comment: @user235562, любой конструктор с одним параметром трактуется как конструктор преобразования типов (похоже на `operator T()`, но с другой стороны знака присваивания).  `explicit` же запрещает подобную трактовку

Comment: @Arhad т.е. приведения int к test, а не наоборот?

Comment: @user235562, да. Конструктор же принадлежит типу `test`, соответственно экземпляр этого типа и создаётся.

Comment: @Arhad понятно, но тогда получается, что `test x = 5` это вообще отдельный синтаксис, а не синтаксическай сахар над `test x(5)`? зачем тогда вообще нужен первый вариант?

Comment: @user235562, для унификации. Мы просто присваиваем объекты, а как они будут преобразовываться (через конструктор или оператор преобразования) волнует только авторов соответствующих классов.

Answer (score 3):

В первом случае - все прозрачно - это инициализация с помощью литерала (скорее всего я забыл и "по науке" это называется иначе, но не суть). Подобная инициализация применима только к базовым типам (тот же **int**, **double** и тд), поскольку только для них существуют литералы. Этот способ удобен своим кратким синтаксисом

Во втором случае используется конструктор (да, у базовых типпов тоже есть конструкторы) Разницы в принципе никакой (поправьте, если вдруг ошибаюсь, но [вот этот замечательный сервис](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) показывает, что в обоих случаях генерируется одинаковый код).  Преимуществ по сравнению с первым типом нет, но выглядит длиннее и чуть менее интуитивно (в случае с базовыми типами), а потому чаще используется первый вариант.

Третий вариант - это использование списка инициализации, возможности которых были существенно расширены в C++11. В этом случае есть разница - если при использовании первых двух способов вы вместо **int** подсунете например **double**, то компилятор вам ничего  не скажет, а просто неявно преобразует его к **int**. Однако, используя третий вариант, вы увидите ошибку. Например:

```
int a1 = 5.5;  // ошибки нет
int a2(5.5);   // ошибки нет
int a3{ 5.5 }; // ошибка компиляции
```

Comment: int a{ 5.5 }; - нет ошибки
Даже сервис который вы скинули все хорошо компилирует, кстати спасибо за него. 

Но все-таки хочется какой-то более общий вид, ведь была какая-то причина добавить {}

Comment: что касается третьего варианта, то, как я уже писал выше, он добавлен для поддержки списков инициализации (удобная штука, но в случае более сложными, нежели базовые, типами). 

По повод ошибки компиляции - здесь, видимо, есть зависимость от компилятора. Я проверял в Visual C++ и там при попытке запихнуть double вываливается ошибка. Однако gcc ошибки не выдает, хотя, насколько я знаю, подобное поведение заложено в стандарте, а gcc стандарт С++11 реализует целиком (или почти целиком)

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю еще, что фигурные скобки запрещают применение *сужающего преобразования*, т.е. если значение может не поместиться в типе.

Например,

```
int x = 5;
char c(x);   // Компилятор может предупредить о сужающем преобразовании
char s{x};   // Компилятор обязан запретить эту инициализацию
```